# How to find out driver and firmware version of my ESXi Fiber Channel HBA? (via SSH)

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, vmware-vsphere, hba

I have an ESXi 5.5 Server (HP DL380 G7).

How can i figure out the driver and firmeware version of my HP-QLOGIC Fiber Channel HBA via SSH?

I think i am too stupid... :-/

Thx for help.

Comment: You might be!!! But this information is available... Is there a bigger reason on why you need it?

Comment: Hi ewwhite. A partner of me wants to have these information. We will change our SAN in the background and he wants to check the current driver and firmware versions of the ESXi servers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do.

- Look at the ILO interface of the server. It provides hardware and firmware inventory.

[image]

- For the VMware side, you can read their [device/driver identification guide](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1031534)... e.g. from the CLI, you may be able to run `cat /proc/scsi/qlaxx/x` to get the HBA and driver information.

Comment: on my ESXi Server ILO's i don't have the "Device Inventory" site (ESXi is installed with the VMWare iso with included HP drivers etc). I can see all other sites but not this one. And even on the "firmware" site i can't see my QLOGIC Controller. I also saw the hints on your Link. with `esxcfg-scsidevs -a` i see the two Qlogic HBA's but i can't see them with `cat /proc/scsi/xxxx` under the folder /proc/scsi/ i only find the two folders "hpsa" --> smart array and "bnx2i" --> i think thees are my normal nic's...